# Nested foreach loop in a While loop can make the condition for the while loop go over?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop

Here is a little background on what I am trying to create.

I am creating a function called `getNextBilling($dateStart,$dateCount = 20)`

You give it a period length which is the days you want someone to be billed

`$test->period = '2,5,15';`

it takes a starting date which
I have assigned on a test page

`$test->getNextBilling('2015-06-12 00:00:00',2);`

What the function is supposed to do, is make sure if the inputed dates are less than the current date to skip this months billing, which works perfectly.

What doesn't work is that I have a `foreach` loop inside of my while loop to see all the days inputed, I can't find a way to make the code work where it actually just shows the amount of days you want.

example above which shows I want to display **2** days the output is

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2015-06-15
    [2] => 2015-07-02
    [3] => 2015-07-05
    [4] => 2015-07-15
)
```

Here is code of the function

```
// SET START DATE
$startDate = new DateTime($dateStart);
// LOOP
$i = 1;
while($i <= $dateCount){
    // LOOP THROUGH INPUTED DAYS
    foreach($days as $day){
        // CLEAN DAY
        $day = formatNumbersOnly($day);                     
        // SET LAST DAY
        $lastDay = new DateTime($startDate->format('Y-m-d'));
        $lastDay->modify('last day of this month');
        // CHECK FOR PASSED DAY
        if($day > $startDate->format('j')){
            // CHECK FOR 28-29-30-31
            if($day > $lastDay->format('j')){
                // SET NEW DATE
                $startDate->setDate(
                    $startDate->format('Y'),
                    $startDate->format('m'),
                    $lastDay->format('j')
                );
            } else {
                // SET NEW DATE
                $startDate->setDate(
                    $startDate->format('Y'),
                    $startDate->format('m'),
                    $day
                );
            }
            // SET ARRAY
            $nextBilling[$i] = $startDate->format('Y-m-d');

        } else {
            // SKIP
            $i--;
        }
        // INCREASE COUNT
        $i++;
    }               
    // NEXT MONTH
    $startDate->modify('1 month');
    $startDate->setDate($startDate->format('Y'),$startDate->format('m'),1);
}
```

Now I understand where the problem is, it's because of the increasing the count inside of the `foreach` loop however when I put it outside it will only output the last day in days like this:

`Array
(
    [-1] => 2015-06-15
    [0] => 2015-07-15
    [1] => 2015-08-15
    [2] => 2015-09-15
)`

If anyone has any criticism or tips that would be greatly appreciated. I will be continuing on trying to fix it.

**EDIT:** I added a if statment at the beginning of the `foreach` to check if `$i` is greater than `$dateCount` it will break out of the loop. Thanks Twisty for your time and efforts, I appreciate it.

Comment: I do not see where your `foreach` loop closes in your example.

Comment: the foreach closes after `// INCREASE COUNT $i++;`

Comment: Where is `$days` defined?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that, `// EXPLODE CONTENTS TO FIND DAYS
     $days = explode(',', $this->period);`

Comment: And what are the values expected within `$days`?

Comment: @Twisty those values are declared above when you type `$test->period = '2,5,15';`  so they would be 2, 5, 15.

Comment: Why this: `$nextBilling[$i] = $startDate->format('Y-m-d');` and not just `$nextBilling[] = $startDate->format('Y-m-d');`? Also why are you decreasing `$i`?

Comment: Im forcing my array to have the values that I want so it would display 1 to whatever amount of days you want to show. if I don't decrease $i it will spit out `Array
(
    [3] => 2015-06-15
)`  It still is incorrect in the way that I want to display the first 2 and it only gives me one, the decreasing of $i is trying to skip that iteration of the loop

Comment: I use `$nextBilling[$i]` also for easier reading

Comment: Just use `next` or `continue` to move on to the next loop.

Comment: @Twisty If I use contiune it actually does the exact same and displays the same, when I use `next($nextBilling[$i])` it outputs `Array
(
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 2015-06-15
)` I want it to output `Array
(
    [1] => 2015-06-15
    [2] => 2015-07-02
)`

Comment: @Twisty I added a edit to the post, Thanks for your help, I found a work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you found an answer. Here is something I was working on while you found it.

```
// SET START DATE
$startDate = new DateTime($dateStart);
$nextBill = new DateTime();

for($i=1;$i<$countDays;$i++){
    switch(true){
        case ($startDate->format('j') > $days[2]):
            // go to next month
            $nextBill->setDate(
                $startDate->format('Y'),
                $startDate->format('m')+1,
                $days[0];
            );
            break;
        case ($startDate->format('j') > $days[1]):
            // Is start date greater than 2nd billing (5)
            $nextBill->setDate(
                $startDate->format('Y'),
                $startDate->format('m'),
                $days[2];
            );
            break;
        case ($startDate->format('j') > $days[0]):
            // is starteDate greater than 1st billing (2)
            $nextBill->setDate(
                $startDate->format('Y'),
                $startDate->format('m'),
                $days[1];
            );
            break;
        default:
            $nextBill->setDate(
                $startDate->format('Y'),
                $startDate->format('m'),
                $days[0];
            );
    }
    $nextBilling[$i] = $nextBill->format('Y-m-d');
    $startDate = $nextBill->setDate(
        $nextBill->format('Y'),
        $nextBill->format('m'),
        $nextBill->format('j')+1
    );
}
```

This will ensure that if `$startDate` is the 1st of the month, it shows the 2nd, and then the 5th. Id `$startDate` is the 3rd, it will show the 5th and 15th. If `$startDate` is the 20th, it will show the 2nd and 5th of the next month.

Comment: This looks good, however would you have to change to code to allow for more inputted days? when declaring the period the user can, if they want go `period(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

Comment: Yes, you would. You'd want to make a loop based on the `count()` of $days, and decrement.